# Unexpected results when creating 32-bit int from byte array

Tags: c++, data-type

I'm having problems creating a 32-bit integer from a 4-byte array. In the following complete, minimal, and verifiable example, converting a byte array containing `0x00, 0x04, 0x04F, 0x45` results in `4F45` (expected result would be `44F45`). I must be overlooking something fundamental here.... can anyone see where I went wrong?

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while(!Serial);
}

void loop()
{
    uint8_t bytes[4] = {0x00, 0x04, 0x4F, 0x45}; //00044F45
    int32_t theInt = byteArrayToInt32(bytes);
    Serial.println(theInt, HEX); //Print 4F45
    delay(250);
}

uint32_t byteArrayToInt32(uint8_t* bytes)
{
    uint32_t i = 0;
    i |= bytes[0] << 24;
    i |= bytes[1] << 16;
    i |= bytes[2] << 8;
    i |= bytes[3];
    return i;
}
```

Comment: @jsotola in what way?

Comment: @jsotola I went ahead re-tested with it as `uint32_t`, no difference :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to shift `uint8_t` more than 8 bits and then `OR` it with `int32_t`.

You have to `cast` the `uint8_t` to `int32_t` before doing the shift.

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while(!Serial);
}

void loop()
{
    uint8_t bytes[4] = { 0x00, 0x04, 0x4F, 0x45}; //00044F45
    int32_t theInt = byteArrayToInt32(bytes);
    Serial.println(theInt, HEX); //Print 4F45
    delay(1000);
}

int32_t byteArrayToInt32(uint8_t* bytes)
{
    int32_t i = 0;
    i |= (int32_t) bytes[0] << 24;
    i |= (int32_t) bytes[1] << 16;
    i |= (int32_t) bytes[2] <<  8;
    i |= (int32_t) bytes[3];
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Note that if the most significant bit of `bytes[0]` is set, then `(int32_t) bytes[0] << 24` will shift it into the sign bit, which is undefined behavior. It is safer to cast to a `uint32_t`, which can in turn be safely assigned to an `int32_t`.

Comment: Hmm, so doing as you suggested fixes the problem, however I'm very perplexed as to why the left shift by 8 bits worked originally, then?

Comment: it appears that the left shift function uses a 16 bit buffer .... possibly because it uses the same code for 16 bit shifts